# maps v2 get longitude & latitude

Tags: android

I try to get the longitude and latitude when maplongclick:
I am trying to the the longitude and latitude in `onMapLongClick()`:

```
@Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

Double lat =    map.getMyLocation().getLatitude();

Double longi = map.getMyLocation().getLatitude();

}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" tells us nothing about the problem. Does it crash? do you have a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

Double lat = point.latitude; 
Double lng = point.longitude;

}
```

Comment: What are the `Longitude` and `Latitude` classes?

Comment: log cat :
12-27 00:44:45.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 00:44:45.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1789): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 00:44:45.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):  at fitness.coter.serveur.Maps.onMapLongClick(Maps.java:86)
12-27 00:44:45.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1789):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$7.onMapLongClick(Unknown Source)

Comment: @saopayne I asked you because you had `Longitude` and `Latitude` as classes for the `lat` and `lng` variables; There are no such clases in Android.

Comment: The method getLatitude() is undefined for the type LatLng